# How to add div for dynamic Check box

Tags: jquery, checkbox, size

Hai i have Created a checkbox dynamically,,But the Size is very small so i decided to add image .Here i cannot append the div to add the image.

is any way to resize the Checkbox?or any other way.

My Code

```
        $optionInput = $('<input />');
        $optionInput.attr({
       'name' : 'ckbox_'+results.rows.item(i).PollId,
       'type' : 'checkbox'
        }).val(arrOption[o]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try style the checkbox

```
$optionInput = $('<input />');
        $optionInput.attr({
       'name' : 'ckbox_'+results.rows.item(i).PollId,
       'type' : 'checkbox'
        }).css({
          'height' : '28px'
        }).val(arrOption[o]);
```